# Swing Application window not showing changes

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm making a java proyect using eclipse and the windowbuilder plugin. After finishing the logic I've created an Application Window and execute the project, everything is fine. But now i want to modify the window, so i change the title for example. In the visual view, i can see these changes, but when i execute the application, there are no changes, it's always the same window. This is the code:

```
public class Application {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Application window = new Application();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Application() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("My Application");
    }

}
```

I've just added one line so I don't know what could be wrong. I also want to know if this is the best way to make a gui application (using Application Window) or if there are better ways.

EDIT: I add some images to show which is the problem

Window when i execute:

[image: Window when i execute]

Window in windowbuilder:

[image: Window in windowbuilder]

Comment: what did you add? frame.setTitle?

Comment: yes, but if i change other things like frame.setBounds() it doesn´t work either

Comment: you are executing in Eclipse or did you make .exe and starting from desktop?

Comment: If I remember well, you should click somewhere on SAVE in windowbuilder after making some changes...

Comment: And after all, if this not works, you can consider some exorcism also... Maybe is a touch of religion or something...

Comment: I'm executing from eclipse, all the changes are saved and everything is in the code

Comment: The only thing what comes to my mind is that you might have font-color set to white and you have also white title label in the frame top.

Comment: I've already tested that, but it's not the problem. No change is shown, no matter what i modify

Answer (score 1):

You can set title using two ways:

1.Set title using JFrame setTitle() method : `frame.setTitle("My Application");`

2.Set title using JFrame(String Title) constructor: `frame = new JFrame("My Application");`

According to my opinion both ways work to set title but still if you are struggling with first option, you can try second option. May be this code works for you.

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("My Application");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: I agree with @ZoranBajcer that you should reinstall swing.

Answer (score 0):

After setting changes, go `frame.dispose()`

and after that You can

```
frame.repaint();
frame.revalidate();
```

Comment: How can this help? It only closes the window...?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
               try {
                    Application window = new Application();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    window.frame.setTitle("My Application");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
```

And let me know the result.

Edit:
   remove setTitle() from initialize method.

Edit: 
   If you are beginner you can try JavaFX. It is also simple as Java Swing but has some more potential, better design options and stuff. Its something I have tryed with when I was started Java learning.

Comment: I just copy-paste your code to my eclipse and it works. Can you make some screenshot of you window?

Comment: I've added the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should delete your swing and install it again. Because any solution is not working and there is no other reason not to. Just try to reinstall swing.